# Trying CashApp to add funds and purchase Bitcoin immediately but not working, Have done all banking requirements, IS THERE ALTERNATIVE

Tags: cash-app

Details: I was successful in entering in my bank information on Cash App however, keeps saying transfer failed even in the process of adding cash into the app from my bank, so I can use that to buy bitcoin immediately, And of cash app will not let me buy bitcoin using my debit card and there is always a routing number always showing that I did not enter(I assume that is Cash App routing for my new[just started it 6-12-2020]cash app account? The app doesn't say which place it is pulling from except for the 1st time..

**I am wondering what the common causes are..could 1 be you must be connected to wi-fi, if so why since I do other transactions this way without connecting to wi-fi

**If CashApp is just too much trouble, WHAT IS ANOTHER APP TO INSTANTLY UPLOAD YOUR BANK INFO AND BUY BITCOIN not a 7-10 day thing__?...Does CoinBase now do immediate purchase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy bitcoin through Simplex using the Abra app. You could also make an arrangement with a Bitcoin seller on LocalBitcoin.com.

If you can connect with a miner directly you can get around these fees, verification, and BS waiting periods when purchasing Bitcoin. Reaching out on online mining communities could go a long way.

Comment: I value and appreciate your conciseness, unfortunately I am not aware of a whole lot yet so I understand and get your general gist, yet to apply(wisely use)may take some other correlating or simple key leanings especially regarding connecting with miners, yet I have thought that because it is the way to produce a value so it has a value along with the system of bitcoin itself. I will start digging into Simplex using Abra app uses & ease and progress from there. Thank you very much, & am always available & glad to exchange info. Sincerely, Mark